# Using Axios to fetch XML Data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, api, axios

I'm relatively new to making REST API calls.

I have a form that the user fills out which include first name, last name, department, and start date.

I learned about Axios and this is what I'm using my in my React application. My current code looks like this:

```
    axios.get('MyAPILocationHere/users', {
        params: {
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            departmentCode: this.state.department,
        }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });
```

However for my school project the Web API is using .NET Framework. And to get the response results it needs to be something like this:

```
http://rdc-servernamehere-vm:6001/api/users/nameLast/HANKS/nameFirst/TOM/departmentCode/MATH
```

When I view that link, it's also an XML file. How do I change my current code to pass my parameters to be able to get the response needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
axios.get(`http://rdc-servernamehere-vm:6001/api/users/nameLast/${this.state.firstName}/nameFirst/${this.state.lastName}/departmentCode/${this.state.department}`
   })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response); // this will print xml data structure
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // always executed
    });
```

And you should import xml to json conversion library at the top.

```
const convert = require("xml-js");
...
function (response) {
   console.log(response); // this will print xml data structure
   const data = JSON.parse(
    convert.xml2json(response.data, { compact: true, spaces: 2 })
  );
  this.setState({ userList: data  }); // you can use this.state.userList to view users
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response is this the package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js` or is it this one `https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js`

Comment: @mustafaBattalogu I get this error here now : 'res' is not defined  no-undef for this line here `convert.xml2json(res.data, { compact: true, spaces: 2 })`

Comment: hisusu32, sorry. you should write as `convert.xml2json(response.data, { compact: true, spaces: 2 })`

Comment: you should use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js` package